# Deploying Docker containers to Windows server

Tags: visual-studio, docker, kubernetes, deployment, containers

There a lot of stuff regarding dockerizing apps in Visual Studio.I successfully managed to create ,run and debug my net.core app in Visual studio using local docker desktop ,wsl2 and kubernetes systems.

But it totally unclear how my app can be deployed to Windows server ,except azure deployment. How can I set in my visual studio or Windows terminal servers docker and kubernetes server instead of my local ?Just can't find any worth tutorials.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Linux containers can run on Windows Server, so you don't need any special tutorials but simply install Docker engine on Windows.

Comment: Are you asking about Linux containers or Windows containers? I'm not sure we officially support Kubernetes under WSL though it probably works if you hammer on it hard enough. We do strongly support native Windows usage with Windows containers, though setup is a bit more complex than Linux and many installers don't support Windows (yet).

Comment: @LexLi I managed that, though my goal is to deploy and run projects on production windows server.

Comment: You have to be very clear on what is your goal. If you want to host on Windows Server alone and no Docker involved, the guide is separate, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0 You'd better find some video clips to get better understanding of the steps.

Comment: I work with IIS hosting for years , so that post is not very usefull for me,I am just asking for docker deployment guide . 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @alekoo73, which Visual Studio's extension do you use currently to connect to your local dev Kubernetes cluster (Kubernetes server included in Docker for Windows - WSL2), [Bridge to Kubernetes ?](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.mindaro), if so in simple terms you should just switch kube context from current "docker-desktop" to your desired one e.g. "staging", like explained on MS sites [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/bridge-to-kubernetes?view=vs-2019#check-the-cluster), app deployment procedure remains the same like in dev.